# How to conditionally remove rows of a matrix in a loop

Tags: r

I have this matrix named `d`.

This is the `d` matrix

```
     V1    V2       V3       V4
1    I     14.06863 11.50424 333173.1
2    N     14.50265 11.89501 387709.7
3    I     14.55234 11.95746 402124.0
4    I     14.78606 12.14149 453059.3
5    N     15.16970 12.51004 496142.1
6    D     14.41104 11.81296 539661.3
7    D     14.86976 12.23968 603475.4
```

I find the

```
d$Delta_Cost <- c(0, diff(d[, 4]))
d$Delta_LY <- c(0, diff(d[, 2]))
```

I need to loop through the matrix and remove the row that fulfills this condition

```
Delta_Cost>0 & Delta_LY<0
```

But i don't know how to do this in R.

Thank you!

Comment: I see no "best" object here

Comment: see row: d$Best[which(with(d, Delta_Cost>0 & Delta_LY<0))] <- "best"

Comment: still no "best" object ... You assign a string. Maybe you want `d$Best == "best"`

Comment: well yes, that's what i'm looking for

Comment: @Dea12: Welcome to SO.  Your question could be made clearer if you showed us what `d` contains and told us what you are trying to solve.  It looks a bit like you are trying to find a minimum value in your matrix, but you don't say so.  Also there are odd things in your code like defining `d$ICER`, which you never use, and defining `d$Best` twice, and unnecessarily calling `which`, and overwriting `d` in that last line.

Comment: Yes, well, so my d matrix contains a matrix with 3 columns and 7 rows, i find the Delta_Cost and Delta_LY for the matrix so i can assign the best string to the row that fulfills the condition, and then i need to remove the row that contains best, then i need to find again the delta costs and delta_ly and do the same, i need to loop it until there is no more best string assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reproducible version of your data:

```
d <- read.table(
  text = "
     V1    V2       V3       V4
1    I     14.06863 11.50424 333173.1
2    N     14.50265 11.89501 387709.7
3    I     14.55234 11.95746 402124.0
4    I     14.78606 12.14149 453059.3
5    N     15.16970 12.51004 496142.1
6    D     14.41104 11.81296 539661.3
7    D     14.86976 12.23968 603475.4",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Since you want the contents of the loop to be run at least once, you want a `repeat` loop rather han a `while`loop.  `to_remove` is a logical vector which is `TRUE` whenever you want to remove the row.  If there are no rows to remove, `if(!any(to_remove))`, we break out of the loop.

```
repeat
{    
  Delta_Cost <- c(0, diff(d[, 4]))
  Delta_LY <- c(0, diff(d[, 2]))    
  to_remove <- Delta_Cost > 0 & Delta_LY < 0 
  if(!any(to_remove))
  {
    break
  }
  d <- d[!to_remove, ]
}
d
##   V1       V2       V3       V4
## 1  I 14.06863 11.50424 333173.1
## 2  N 14.50265 11.89501 387709.7
## 3  I 14.55234 11.95746 402124.0
## 4  I 14.78606 12.14149 453059.3
## 5  N 15.16970 12.51004 496142.1
```

Comment: I get this:Error: object 'best' not found

Comment: As Julien pointed out in his comments, you need to define a variable called `best`.  This needs to happen before the `while` loop.  You should then change the value of `best` at the point when the loop should exit.

Comment: could you please take a look at my modified code, i made it much simpler, please

Comment: If the answer is useful to you, you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow on the left next to the tick.